# Initializing GenServer state with more than one thing

Tags: elixir, state, erlang-otp

I want to create a GenServer that requires more than one piece of state in the beginning. In particular the `init` function kicks off a timer that needs to know a few pieces of initial state. I understand that the second argument to `GenServer.start_link`is passed directly into `init(arg)`.

However I can't find an example that shows how to pass more than one argument of state in for initialization in `init`. For example something desirable would be:

```
defmodule Application.Test do
  require GenServer

  def start_link(state1, state2) do 
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [state1, state2], [])
  end 

  def init(state) do
    # Use the state to launch timer
  end
end
```

However, since I can'
t find an example, and I'm really new to elixir, this doesnt seem idiomatic to me. Is there a better/more efficient way to do this, or is this the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your states in a `Tuple` or `Struct` like this:

```
start_link(state1, state2) do
  Genserver.start_link(__MODULE__, {state1, state2}, [])
end

# use pattern matching to extract the states
def init({state1, state2}) do
  # use state1 and state2
end
```

Comment: I prefer to use map - tuple is not best choice when you want to edit it, also struct, because you can't add new keys.

Comment: Sure you can use whatever is best for the situation - i just used a tuple here since in the example there are just 2 variables to wrap.